# Users not appearing on dialogflow agent share tab

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am the admin/owner of a dialogflow GCP account. I gave reviewer access to a user via the Share tab on the Agent view of the console. That user can now login with their email - he says its working. However, the user does not appear on my admin view of the agent. It's like it disappeared. Why can't I see the other user's on my Agent console view?

using Standard Edition

thanks, Ted

Comment: You just need to wait for some time. To see the list of reviewers (or other roles) it usually takes some time.

Comment: I see. So multiple days? It's been more than a week.

Comment: haha, no not that long. What I meant was that it does not instantly reflect the change.